# AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'groupby' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that has 3 columns -

[image]

I want to group the columns on the basis of Chopstick Length by doing something like this -

```
meansByCL = df_chopstick.groupby('Chopstick.Length')['Food.Pinching.Efficiency'].mean().reset_index()
```

but this throws an error -

```
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'groupby' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

I'm not sure what this error means. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or how I can write this code differently?

Comment: What is your `df_chopstick`, looks like it is already a groupby object

Comment: @KevinFang df_chopstick is the image attached. It has Food.Pinching.Efficiency for different chopstick lengths(180-240) and different individuals (1-31).

Comment: Please double check whether it is modified elsewhere. I can reproduce this error when I call `df.groupby().groupby()`

Comment: Never mind! Found what I was doing wrong. I had assigned `df_chopstick = df_chopstick.groupby('Chopstick.Length')` in a previous cell of Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens when you are trying to `groupby()` a dataframe which has been already grouped before!

Comment: ...and the solution is to ungroup it with `unstack()` or `reset_index()`

Comment: unstack /reset_index when? before? after? during?

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I have done a groupby and it was not required. I needed to use original dataset and just Index it (not groupby it).
So remove the groupby and use below to set_index.
Yeah the problem is that groupby is already done and you can't groupby it again.

```
df.set_index(['ColA','ColB'])
```