# Error "Cannot access callable attribute 'sample' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method"

Tags: python, pandas, sampling

Mock data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        'country': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Canada', 'Canada', 'Canada', 'USA', 'Canada']
})
```

Let's say I want to sample one observation for each country:

```
df.groupby('country').sample(1)
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'sample' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

I have tried to reset the index, it didn't solve the problem. I have also tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53406056/attributeerror-cannot-access-callable-attribute-groupby-of-dataframegroupby), it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: this question has a follow up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65979343/random-sample-by-group-how-to-specify-n-not-weight-using-dataframegroupby-sa).

Comment: Do you just want a dataframe that has 1 row per country? a random row? the first row? the row with the max id?

Comment: I want a random number of n rows, for each country.  However my question is general here: why does the function  DataFrameGroupBy.sample does not work as expected? See doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html

Comment: I just run exactly the same code as you posted, and the code runs without errors.

Comment: sophods thanks, any ideas why this might be the case?

Comment: What pandas version are you using?

Comment: version is 0.24.2

Comment: @johnjohn `groupby.sample` is introduced in pandas `version 1.1.0.` so you might have to upgrade pandas.

Comment: Yes exactly, Using version ```'1.2.0'```, your code works just fine.

Comment: Many thanks both, indeed it was a version issue! Now let’s say I also want a different number of rows for each country (say, 4 random rows for USA, 2 random rows for Canada): I've tried: df.groupby("country").sample(n=[4, 2]) but it didn't work. Can you help (note I need to specify n, and not proportion of data or weight as in the doc)? Or do I need to post a new question for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the per the error use `apply()`. `group_keys=False` will remove the additional index of `country`.

```
>>> df.groupby('country', group_keys=False).apply(lambda df: df.sample(1))
   id country
6   7  Canada
2   3     USA
```

Edit:
Seems to be a mismatch of Pandas versions as `groupby` was introduced in `version 1.1.0`. I ran the OPs code and it works as well.

You will need to upgrade pandas using `pip3 install --upgrade pandas`

Comment: OK, thanks, but why does the function DataFrameGroupBy.sample does not work as expected, see here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html ? Also, it seems to me your solution always return the same rows. I need a random sample.

Comment: It is random I tested it out, try running it a few times. Actually your code does work as well. I just tried it out. What version of pandas are you using? I am using `1.2.1`.

Comment: many thanks, it was a version issue indeed. One more question: I also want a different number of rows for each country (say 4 for USA, 2 for Canada): I've tried: df.groupby("country").sample(n=[4, 2]) but it didn't  work. Can you help (using my method instead of lambda please, and also specifying n and not a weight)?

Comment: @johnjohn I am not too sure I would suggest creating another question for that. Could you accept my answer as well?