# Random sample by group: how to specify n, not weight? (using DataFrameGroupBy.sample)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, sampling

This question follows [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65978749/error-cannot-access-callable-attribute-sample-of-dataframegroupby-objects) (I was asked to post it as a new question by other contributors).

We have this mock df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        'country': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'Canada', 'Canada', 'Canada', 'USA', 'Canada']
})
```

Let's say I want to sample 4 random rows from USA and 2 random rows from Canada. I've tried:

```
df.groupby("country").sample(n=[4, 2])
```

This returns an error. The mistake is probably the use of square brackets. How to specify different n for each group, then?

Note ideally I need a solution using df.groupby.sample. Also note I need to specify n, not proportion or weight as in documentation (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html)). Finally note I also need to set a seed. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `group` the dataframe on `country` then [`.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) each group separately where the number of samples to take can be obtained from the dictionary, finally [`.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) all the sampled groups:

```
d = {'USA': 4, 'Canada': 2} # mapping dict
pd.concat([g.sample(d[k]) for k, g in df.groupby('country', sort=False)])
```

---

```
   id country
0   1     USA
4   5     USA
1   2     USA
2   3     USA
6   7  Canada
9  10  Canada
```

Comment: many thanks Shubham Sharma. Importantly, I also need to set a seed. Can we add an argument for this, e.g., random_state = x? And if we can, where? (I updated my question to mention need of seed).

Comment: @johnjohn yes we can pass the argument in `sample` call like `g.sample(d[k], random_state=<some value>)`